# Equivalence relation on $\mathbb C[x]$ and $\operatorname{card}\left(\mathbb C[x]_{/ \sim}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

> An equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb C[x]$ is defined in the
>   following way:
>
> Two polynomials $p,q\in\mathbb C[x]$ are equivalent if their
>   zero-points sets are equal.
>
> Prove $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and find
>   $\operatorname{card}\left(\mathbb C[x]_{/ \sim}\right)$

My attempt:

Let $S:\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k:\alpha_i\in\mathbb C\}$ be zero-points set of two polynomials $p,q\in\mathbb C[x]$. Then:
$$(x-\alpha_i)\mid p\;\land\;\;(x-\alpha_i)\mid q\;\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$$
It can be proven very easily the relation is reflexive, symmetric & transitive, so I didn't have any problems with that part.

I'm concerned about my statement I didn't know how to prove concisely:
$$\operatorname{card}\left(\mathbb C[x]_{/ \sim}\right)=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb C)=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb R^2)=\operatorname{card}(\mathbb R)=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$$

Is that true, and if so, how can I prove it?
This task appeared on our elementary math 1 exam, so I haven't been introduced to tools regarding measure that I saw in most of the posts. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any set $X$, let $X^{<\omega}$ denote the set of finite subsets of $X$. It can be shown that if $X$ is infinite, then $X$ and $X^{<\omega}$ have the same cardinality.

You can get a bijection from $\Bbb{C}[x]/{\sim}$, the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$, to $\Bbb{C}^{<\omega}$, the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb{C}$. Just map each finite subset $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\}\subseteq\Bbb{C}$ to the equivalence class of $\prod_{i=1}^n(x-\alpha_i)$. Note that the empty set gets mapped to the equivalence class of the constant polynomial $1$.

Hence we have that

$$card(\Bbb{C}[x]/{\sim})=card(\Bbb{C}^{<\omega})=card(\Bbb{C})=2^{\aleph_0}.$$